Issue with Geocoding Addresses in MMQGIS Plugin Despite Correct Preprocessing
I'm using the MMQGIS plugin to geocode a list of addresses, and I've carefully preprocessed the addresses to ensure they match perfectly with the street layer being used. While the majority of addresses are geocoded correctly, some fail unexpectedly, even though the street names are correct, and the house numbers fall within valid ranges for those streets.
Upon inspecting a few failed cases, I noticed that the "Left from/to" and "Right from/to" fields contain NAs for certain streets. This seems to occur mostly on larger streets, where the even and odd sides have separate linestrings.
Could these NAs be causing the geocoding to fail, or is there something else I should investigate?
